# Virtual box network connections

Tags: virtualbox

I was searching for a solution to setup network connection to my virtualbox

I am having Windows and linux boxes in my virtual box environment. As I need to keep static IP address for my connection, i am having challenges when i connect from office as the office subnet range is different to home.

I have installed virtual box on Mac laptop. There are 4 VM's (3 linux and 1 windows). Following conditions are to be met in order to carry out my testing at home and to do demo at the office.

1. My virtualbox needs to connect to the Internet at office and home (office lan is 10.10.*.* and home lan is 192.168.*.*)
2. Want to use static ip address for all my VM machines
3. All the VM's must be able to talk to each other.
4. Not necessary, but it should have been nice, if i can transfer the files from my mac os (where virtual box is installed) to the VM's (kind of drag and drop)

I tried different options - NAT and host only connections then Bridge adapter and host only connection. Nothing worked as per the above criteria.

Pls let me know, if you need any further information

Comment: Let's take #4 install VirtualBox guest additions to every VM and you are able to drag&drop.

Comment: Thanks a lot Biswa. But do you have any knowledege on how to use the same static ip address even if i am at office or home with internet connection and also able VM talk to each other?

Comment: I think I have found the answer.. need to test it..I have put 2 interface, one for static and one act as NAT.

Comment: I think I have found the answer.. need to test it..I have put 2 interface on all the machines,Host only which has static interface will take care off the connection between the VM's and other one NAT which will help me to connect to the internet. Will test it from the office.. works fine when i am connected at home

Comment: Write your answer with details with some screenshots in the answer section below.